Arbitrary depth tree represented by a nested dictionary of lists to pandas DataFrame
I am trying to get a pandas dataframe from a nested dictionary that contains lists of children nodes. The depth and amount of nodes is completely uneven. Here I put an example of the dictionary that I am trying to convert to a Pandas Dataframe. My dictionary is much longer, it has more than 600 nodes but it has the same format as this example.
example_dict = {"id": 0, "children":[{"id":4},
                                 {"id": 1, "children":[{"id":2}, {"id":6}, {"id":7}, {"id":8}]},
                                 {"id": 3, "children":[{"id":5}]},
                                {"id": 9, "children":[{"id":10},
                                                      {"id": 11, "children":[{"id":12},
                                                                             {"id":13},
                                                                             {"id":14},
                                                                             {"id":15}]}]},
                                {"id": 16, "children":[{"id":17},
                                                       {"id":18},
                                                       {"id":19},
                                                       {"id":20},
                                                       {"id": 21, "children":[{"id":22},
                                                                              {"id": 23, "children":[{"id":24}]}]}]}]}

I want to convert it into a dataframe that looks like this:
|    |   Level 1 |   Level 2 | Level 3   | Level 4   | Level 5   |
|---:|----------:|----------:|:----------|:----------|:----------|
|  0 |         0 |         4 | <NA>      | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  1 |         0 |         1 | 2         | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  2 |         0 |         1 | 6         | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  3 |         0 |         1 | 7         | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  4 |         0 |         1 | 8         | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  5 |         0 |         3 | 5         | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  6 |         0 |         9 | 10        | <NA>      | <NA>      |
|  7 |         0 |         9 | 11        | 12        | <NA>      |
|  8 |         0 |         9 | 11        | 13        | <NA>      |
|  9 |         0 |         9 | 11        | 14        | <NA>      |
| 10 |         0 |         9 | 11        | 15        | <NA>      |
| 11 |         0 |        16 | 17        | <NA>      | <NA>      |
| 12 |         0 |        16 | 18        | <NA>      | <NA>      |
| 13 |         0 |        16 | 19        | <NA>      | <NA>      |
| 14 |         0 |        16 | 20        | <NA>      | <NA>      |
| 15 |         0 |        16 | 21        | 22        | <NA>      |
| 16 |         0 |        16 | 21        | 23        | 24        |

Target Table
The number of columns depends on the dictionary so the solution needs to add as many columns as needed.
I tried the solutions here but I could not get a solution.
Any depth nested dict to pandas dataframe

Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (for print(df)) or table formatting (from print(df.to_markdown()).

Show what you tried please. From a glance, this looks like you just need to walk the tree and, say, accumulate each branch as a list. Is that something you tried? If it didn't work, what went wrong? Don't make us try solutions you've already ruled out. (This advice is given in [ask] ("any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself") and How to make good reproducible pandas examples ("show the code you've tried").)

As @wjandrea stated, expanding your tree into a list of lists wouldn't be hard to do with a recursive function. By the way, the antepenultimate row in your target dataframe shouldn't be there.

@Swifty, how could I do that? I corrected the row you said.

Here's a recursive function that will convert your dictionary to a list of sublists. Note that the sublists are of varying lengths, so you may have some post-treatment to do before making a dataframe out of the list.
def dict_to_lists(my_dict):
    my_list = []
    children = my_dict.get('children')
    if children is None:
        return [[my_dict['id']]]
    for child_dict in children:
        my_list.extend([[my_dict['id']] + child_list for child_list in dict_to_lists(child_dict)])
    return my_list

On your example dict, it returns:
[
    [0, 4], 
    [0, 1, 2], 
    [0, 1, 6], 
    [0, 1, 7], 
    [0, 1, 8], 
    [0, 3, 5], 
    [0, 9, 10], 
    [0, 9, 11, 12], 
    [0, 9, 11, 13], 
    [0, 9, 11, 14], 
    [0, 9, 11, 15], 
    [0, 16, 17], 
    [0, 16, 18], 
    [0, 16, 19], 
    [0, 16, 20], 
    [0, 16, 21, 22], 
    [0, 16, 21, 23, 24]
]

